# How to use CoreData with two view controllers one of them has collection view

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionviewcell

First of all, I am new in coding, so please be patient with me.

My app has two view controller, the first has UICollectionView and the second has UITextField. 
I am trying to tap on  one of these collection view cells and then it takes me to the second view controller, where I can type in the textView then save it into CoreData. And then when I go back and press on the same cell i get my saved text. Then when i change this text on the ui text view.. it saved automatically.

Can any one give me an example or  put me in the right track

Comment: I suggest studying the default Master/Detail application that Xcode will create for you.  It uses a table rather than a collection view but the logic for how to communicate between the controllers should be useful.  (Core Data is for saving application objects rather than just text so it might be overkill for what you've described.)

Answer (score 1):

The essence of how that might be done is to implement the collectionview delegate and then determine which cell they clicked on, so that the next screen loads/and updates the correct data. After they click you would call the "segue" with some code.  The segues are setup in Xcode's visual editor by control click and dragging a line to the second view.  (It's weird, there are some [great youtube videos out there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjBqKaGiZws)) The data would be stored in an array.  After you update the data, you could dismiss the second view and the collectionview behind it would be visible again.

I would check out chapter 4.5 of the free iBook "App Development with Swift". Chapters 4.5-4.8 would really get your rocking the right path.  If that book is too complex then also look into "Intro to App Development with Swift"

[image: iBook app development with swift]

I even have some videos to take you through the process, dunno if I have one for 4.5 but if you continue with it, I have one for 4.6.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5u9SGhQoPY&t=2254s